(Solved) Unity - How can I fix the mesh shape?
My mesh, which is supposed to be a square, is a rectangle for some reason and doesn't fit the vertexes at all. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I haven't figured anything out.
I tried to look in the part of the program where the triangles are generated, and what values are generated there, but I didn't find anything wrong
Thank you for all the answers
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    Mesh mesh;

    Vector3[] vertices;
    int[] triangles;

    public int Size = 20;

    public float scale = 0.3f;

    public int octaves;
    public float presistance;
    public float lacunarity;

    public int seed;
    public Vector2 offset;

    public TerrainType[] regions;

    Texture2D texture;

    Vector2[] uvs;

    public Material mat;
    public float heightMultiplier = 20f;

    public AnimationCurve curve;

    float[,] heightMap;

    public GameObject treePrefab;

    void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        mesh.name = "Mesh";

        heightMap = GenerateNoiseMap(Size, scale, seed, octaves, presistance, lacunarity, offset);

        CreateShape();
        UpdateMesh();

    }

    void CreateShape()
    {
        vertices = new Vector3[(Size + 1) * (Size + 1)];
        Color[] colourMap = new Color[(Size + 1) * (Size + 1)];

        float[,] treeHeightMap = GenerateNoiseMap(Size, scale, seed + 3, octaves, presistance, lacunarity, offset);

        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= Size; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= Size; x++)
            {                
                float currentHeight = curve.Evaluate(heightMap[x, z]) * heightMultiplier;

                for (int j = 0; j < regions.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (currentHeight <= regions[j].height)
                    {
                        colourMap[z * Size + x] = regions[j].colour;
                    }
                }

                if (treeHeightMap[x, z] >= .5f && currentHeight > 2)
                {
                    GameObject tree = Instantiate(treePrefab);

                    tree.transform.position = new Vector3(x, currentHeight, z);
                }

                vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
                i++;
            }
        }

        texture = new Texture2D(Size, Size);
        texture.SetPixels(colourMap);
        texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
        texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        texture.Apply();

        mat.mainTexture = texture;

        triangles = new int[Size * Size * 6];

        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < Size; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Size; x++)
            {
                triangles[tris] = vert;
                triangles[tris + 1] = vert + Size + 1;
                triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;

                triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 4] = vert + Size + 1;
                triangles[tris + 5] = vert + Size + 2;

                vert++;
                tris += 6;
            }
            vert++;
        }

        uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= Size; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= Size; x++)
            {
                uvs[i] = new Vector2((float)x / Size, (float)z / Size);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.uv = uvs;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();

        GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = mesh;
    }

    float[,] GenerateNoiseMap(int size, float scale, int seed, int octaves, float presistance, float lacunarity, Vector2 offset)
    {
        float[,] noiseMap = new float[size + 1, size + 1];

        System.Random prng = new System.Random(seed);
        Vector2[] octaveOffsets = new Vector2[octaves + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= octaves; i++)
        {
            float offsetX = prng.Next(-100000, 100000) + offset.x;
            float offsetZ = prng.Next(-100000, 100000) + offset.y;

            octaveOffsets[i] = new Vector2(offsetX, offsetZ);
        }

        if (scale <= 0)
        {
            scale = 0.0001f;
        }

        float minNoiseHeight = float.MaxValue;
        float maxNoiseHeight = float.MinValue;

        float halfSize = size / 2;

        for (int z = 0; z <= size; z++)
        {
            for(int x = 0;x <= size; x++)
            {

                float amplitude = 1;
                float frequency = 1;
                float noiseHeight = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i <= octaves; i++)
                {
                    float sampleX = (x - halfSize) / scale * frequency + octaveOffsets[i].x;
                    float sampleY = (z - halfSize) / scale * frequency + octaveOffsets[i].y;

                    float perlinValue = Mathf.PerlinNoise(sampleX, sampleY) * 2 - 1;
                    noiseHeight += perlinValue * amplitude;

                    amplitude *= presistance;
                    frequency *= lacunarity;
                }

                if(noiseHeight < minNoiseHeight)
                {
                    minNoiseHeight = noiseHeight;
                }else if(noiseHeight > maxNoiseHeight)
                {
                    maxNoiseHeight = noiseHeight;
                }

                noiseMap[x, z] = noiseHeight;
            }
        }

        for (int z = 0; z <= size; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= size; x++)
            {
                noiseMap[x, z] = Mathf.InverseLerp(minNoiseHeight, maxNoiseHeight, noiseMap[x, z]);

                float fallOffX = z / (float)size * 2 - 1;
                float fallOffZ = x / (float)size * 2 - 1;

                float value = Mathf.Max(Mathf.Abs(fallOffX), Mathf.Abs(fallOffZ));

                noiseMap[x, z] = Mathf.Clamp01(noiseMap[x, z] - Evaluate(value));
            }
        }

        return noiseMap;
    }

    float Evaluate(float value)
    {
        float a = 3;
        float b = 2.2f;

        return Mathf.Pow(value, a) / (Mathf.Pow(value, a) + Mathf.Pow(b - b * value, a));
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct TerrainType
    {
        public string name;
        public float height;
        public Color colour;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.black;
        if(vertices != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            {
                Gizmos.DrawSphere(vertices[i], 0.1f);

            }
        }
    }
}

Mesh with vertices:

Mesh with trees that I can't generate on a supernumerary mesh:


I don't know why, but it worked when I created a new project and for some reason the mesh was square
